# How can we make async_task run as per the scheduled time using Ruby Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous, task

As per new enhancement request, we need to setup a TEST environment(EDDIE-TEST) from Production environment(EDDIE-PROD) in linux using Ruby Rails and we were able to setup successfully.

But we are facing issues, while loading data into the Test Environment (EDDIE-TEST).

We have some async_tasks which run as per the scheduled time to load data into PROD environment(EDDIE-PROD).But the same tasks are not working in TEST Environment.

Please refer below details for better understanding.

Below one is the code for setting up TEST environment from PROD.

```
cd /opt
mkdir EDDIE
svn checkout https://xxxxxxxxx.com/sss/ttttt/EDDIE/trunk EDDIE
cd EDDIE/
yum -y install httpd
cp config/setup/eddie.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/eddie.conf
service httpd start
groupadd rvm
usermod -a -G rvm root
echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
curl -L http://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
rvm install 2.0.0
yum -y install p7zip
yum -y install freetds
yum -y install freetds-devel
gem install bundler
bundle install
bundle exec rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
thin start -p 3035 -e production --threaded -d
```

The below are the async_task which loads data into PROD. These tasks are running properly as per the scheduled time.

[Status of async_tasks in EDDIE-PROD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HYrr.jpg)

But in Test environment, which is created from EDDIE-PROD, these tasks are not running and we are unable to load data into EDDIE-TEST. Please find the below screen shot for your reference.

[Status of async_tasks in EDDIE-TEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fg33.jpg)

**Can anyone please help me, how can we make these tasks run as per the scheduled time in TEST Environment(EDDIE-TEST) as well?**

Devices.update method will load into devices table from DDMI database. Here is my devices.rb file from "app/models" folder.

```
include MysqlHelper
include ApplicationHelper
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :label, :last_scan, :scan_file_name, :operating_system_id, :hostname
  attr_accessible :preferred_ip_address, :netbios, :name, :ddmi_server_id, :ddmi_server_status, :duplicate_of_device

  has_many :supportal_host
  has_many :supportal_applications, :through => :supportal_host
  has_many :radia_host
  has_many :spig_email
  belongs_to :operating_system
  belongs_to :ddmi_server
  has_one :agent_installation
  has_one :agent_installation_type, :through => :agent_installations
  has_many :smit_tool_installations
  has_many :smit_tools, :through => :smit_tool_installations
  belongs_to :icon_category

  scope :active, -> { where(status: "Active") }
  scope :unique, -> { where(duplicate_of_device: nil) }

  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    :preferred_ip_address => "IP Address"
  }

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options = {})
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
  end


  def self.device_group_definitions ip
    DeviceGroupDefinition.where("(start_range <= INET_ATON('#{ip}')) AND (end_range >= INET_ATON('#{ip}'))")
  end


  def device_group_definitions
    DeviceGroupDefinition.where("(start_range <= INET_ATON('#{preferred_ip_address}')) AND (end_range >= INET_ATON('#{preferred_ip_address}'))")
  end


  def self.clean
    null_fields = [  
      "preferred_dns_name",
      "preferred_mac_address",
      "preferred_ip_address",
      "preferred_agent_address",
      "logical_subnet",
      "hostname",
      "description",
      "contact",
      "name",
      "tag",
      "location",
      "device_object_id",
      "department",
      "service_pack",
      "pkg_label",
      "fully_qualified_label",
      "external_system_key",
      "agent_operating_system",
      "agent_version",
      "aum_agent_upgrade_state",
      "ssh_public_key_status",
      "workflow_type",
      "scan_directory",
      "scan_file_name",
      "scanner_version",
      "netbios_workgroup",
      "discovery_rule",
      "snmp_rule",
      "network_rule",
      "agent_rule",
      "scanner_rule",
      "v_rule",
      "mobile_rule",
      "last_seen",
      "last_scan",
      "icon_category_id",
      "custom_dataname",
      "custom_datavalue"
    ]
    null_fields.each do |field|
      Device.update_all("#{field} = NULL", "#{field} = 'NULL' OR #{field} = ''")
    end

    Device.update_all("last_scan = NULL", "last_scan = 0")

    zero_fields = [ 
      "category_id",
      "company_id_hardware",
      "company_id_software",
      "family_id",
      "model_id",
      "operating_system_id",
      "network_function_id",
      "agent_port_number"
    ]
    zero_fields.each do |field|
      Device.update_all("#{field} = NULL", "#{field} = 0")
    end

    Device.update_all("hostname = UPPER(netbios)", "hostname IS NULL AND netbios <> ''")
    Device.update_all("hostname = UPPER(name)", "hostname IS NULL AND name IS NOT NULL AND name <> '' AND name NOT LIKE '%.%' AND name != 'none' AND name NOT LIKE '% %'")
    Device.update_all("hostname = UPPER(scan_file_name)", "hostname IS NULL AND scan_file_name IS NOT NULL AND scan_file_name NOT LIKE '%.%' AND scan_file_name NOT LIKE '%_local$%'")

    Device.where("hostname LIKE '%.%'").each do |device|
      device.update_attributes(:hostname => device.hostname.partition(".").first.upcase)
    end

    Device.where("hostname IS NULL AND scan_file_name IS NOT NULL").each do |device|
      if device.scan_file_name.include? "."
        device.update_attributes(:hostname => device.scan_file_name.partition(".").first.upcase)
      elsif device.scan_file_name.include? "_local$"
        device.update_attributes(:hostname => device.scan_file_name.partition("_local$").first.upcase)
      end
    end

    Device.where("hostname IS NULL AND name LIKE '%.iuser.iroot.adidom.com'").each do |device|
      device.update_attributes(:hostname => device.name[/[^.]+/].upcase)
    end

    @duplicate_devices = Device.select("hostname, preferred_ip_address, CONCAT(hostname, preferred_ip_address), COUNT(CONCAT(hostname, preferred_ip_address)) AS n").group("CONCAT(hostname, preferred_ip_address)").having("n > 1")
    logger.info "Devices with duplicate hostname and IP: #{@duplicate_devices.length}"
    @duplicate_devices.each do |duplicate|
      devices = Device.where("hostname = ? AND preferred_ip_address = ?", duplicate.hostname, duplicate.preferred_ip_address).order("last_scan DESC")
      best = devices.first
      devices.drop(1).each do |device|
        device.update_attribute(:duplicate_of_device, best.id)
      end
    end
  end


  def self.update    
    async_task = AsyncTask.where(:method => "Device.update").first

    async_task.update_attributes(:status => "0% Exporting Database")
    unless MysqlHelper.mysql_query("aggregate", "aggregate_extract.sql", "devices.tsv")
      async_task.update_attributes(:status => "100% Exporting Database Failed")
      return
    end

    async_task.update_attributes(:status => "20% Importing Database")
    unless MysqlHelper.mysql_import(Rails.env, "devices.tsv")
      async_task.update_attributes(:status => "100% Importing Database Failed")
      return
    end

    async_task.update_attributes(:status => "40% Cleaning Data")
    Device.clean

    async_task.update_attributes(:status => "60% Matching Agent Installations to Devices")
    AgentInstallation.find_each do |agent_installation|
      match = Device.find_by_hostname(agent_installation.hostname)
      agent_installation.update_attributes(:device_id => match.id) unless match.nil?
    end

    async_task.update_attributes(:status => "70% Matching SPIG Emails to Devices")
    SpigEmail.find_each do |spig_email|
      match = Device.match spig_email.hostname, spig_email.ip
      spig_email.update_attributes(device_id: match.id) unless match.nil?
    end

    async_task.update_attributes(:status => "80% Get SMIT tools installation data")
    SmitTool.find_each do |smit_tool|
      smit_tool.update_installation_data
    end

    async_task.update_attributes(:status => "100% Complete", :last_run => Time.now)
  end


  def self.match_by_hostname hostname    
=begin
    # want to match to the latest-scanned active device, then deactivated, then deleted  

    match = Device.where("hostname = ?", hostname).order("status ASC, last_scan DESC").first
    return match unless match.nil?
    match = Device.where("label = ?", hostname).order("status ASC, last_scan DESC").first
    return match unless match.nil?
    match = Device.where("name = ?", hostname).order("status ASC, updated DESC").first
    return match unless match.nil?
    match = Device.where("label LIKE ?", "#{hostname}.%").order("status ASC, updated DESC").first
    return match  
=end

    # Edited to match to the latest-scanned device regardless of status
    match = Device.where("hostname = ?", hostname).order("last_scan DESC").first
    return match

  end


  def self.match_by_ip ip
    Device.where("preferred_ip_address = ? AND hostname IS NULL", ip).order("status ASC, updated DESC").first
  end


  def self.match hostname, ip = nil
    match = Device.match_by_hostname hostname unless hostname.nil?
    return match unless match.nil?
    match = Device.match_by_ip ip unless ip.nil?
    return match
  end


  def duplicate_hostnames
    Device.active.where("hostname = ? AND id != ?", self.hostname, self.id)
  end


  def duplicate_ips
    Device.active.where("preferred_ip_address = ? AND id != ?", self.preferred_ip_address, self.id)
  end


  def ddmi_url
    "url-of-ddmi"
  end

end
```

Please let me know in case of any additional information, you people need to resolve this issue.

Thanks much..!

-
Pawan